# aggregating gradle multiproject test results using TestReport

Tags: build, automated-tests, gradle

I have a project structure that looks like the below. I want to use the [TestReport](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestReport.html) functionality in Gradle to aggregate all the test results to a single directory.
Then I can access all the test results through a single index.html file for ALL subprojects.
How can I accomplish this?

```
.
|--ProjectA
  |--src/test/...
  |--build
    |--reports
      |--tests
        |--index.html (testresults)
        |--..
        |--..
|--ProjectB
    |--src/test/...
      |--build
        |--reports
          |--tests
            |--index.html (testresults)
            |--..
            |--..
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

From [Example 4. Creating a unit test report for subprojects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#test_reporting) in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html):

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    // Disable the test report for the individual test task
    test {
        reports.html.enabled = false
    }
}

task testReport(type: TestReport) {
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/allTests")
    // Include the results from the `test` task in all subprojects
    reportOn subprojects*.test
}
```

Fully working sample is available from `samples/testing/testReport` in the full Gradle distribution.

Comment: Hey Pete, I need some direction. In my case, I have only one project i.e. ProjectA and after gradle clean build integrationTest, I see build/jacoco/test.exec and build/jacoco/integrationTest.exec. Under build/reports/tests/xxxxxx I see either index.html for Unit tests or only Integration tests i.e. if I run gradle clean build, I see unit tests index.html and if I run gradle clean build integrationTest, then it overwrites the data in build/reports/tests/xxx and gets the new data for integrationTest task in the same folder (build/reports/tests).

Comment: Similarly, When I run sonar-runner, I do see both .exec files getting picked during JacocoSensor and I also see jacoco overall .exec getting created in the workspace under .sonar folder and under build/reports/jacoco folder. sonar-runner completes successfully, but I dont see the results in project's dashboard in Sonar even though I have both widgets set for showing Unit tests/coverage and Integration tests. Please advise what I may be missing.

Comment: You need to set a separate report dir for integration tests (see [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html)). Not sure about the Sonar problem.

Comment: `testReport` is deprecated in Gradle 1.9 and shouldn't be used any more.

Comment: It's only the `test.testReport` property that's deprecated. As the deprecation message says, you just need to replace it with `test.reports.html.enabled = false`.

Comment: I'm just saying :) also, this doesn't work unless (like the questioner asked) both projects are in subdirectories; I had my parent project in the root directory, to no avail.

Comment: The question is about aggregating the test reports of all subprojects. The answer works regardless of the directory layout.

Comment: I have found that if one test fail, task report is not completed - neither the rest of the tests are executed, so is needed to add `ignoreFailures` to `test` task ([source](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-if-junits-fail-the-build-is-failing-without-executing-the-next-test-case/6868/7)).

Comment: How I like when people pointing to /current/ url in documentation, as if this chapter be there forever.

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.2/userguide/java_testing.html#test_reporting

Comment: Could not get unknown property 'test' for project ':my-subproject' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: It's better to use `reportOn getTasksByName("test", true)` since that'll work if some subprojects doesn't have any test tasks

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the `subprojects` block and `testReport` task suggested by [@peter-niederwieser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84889/peter-niederwieser) above, I would add another line to the build below those:

```
tasks('test').finalizedBy(testReport)
```

That way if you run `gradle test` (or even `gradle build`), the `testReport` task will run after the subproject tests complete. Note that you have to use `tasks('test')` rather than just `test.finalizedBy(...)` because the `test` task doesn't exist in the root project.

Comment: I had to do the following fopr Gradle 5.6.2: ```rootProject.getTasksByName('test', true).each {
 it.finalizedBy(testReport)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I am posting updated answer on this topic. I am using Gradle 7.5.1.

### TestReport task

In short I'm using following script to set up test aggregation form subprojects (based on @Peter's answer):

```
subprojects {
  apply plugin: 'java'
}

task testReport(type: TestReport) {
  destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/allTests")
  // Include the results from the `test` task in all subprojects
  testResults.from = subprojects*.test
}
```

Note that `reportOn` method is "deprecated" or will be soon and replaced with `testResults`, while at the same time `testResults` is still incubating as of 7.5.1.
I got following warning in IDE

```
The TestReport.reportOn(Object...) method has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0.
```

Hint: `subproject*.test` is example of [*star dot*](http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#Collections-Gettingefficientwiththestar-dotoperator) notation in groovy that invokes test task on a list of subprojects. Equally would be invocation of `subprojects.collect{it.test}`

- [TestReport#reportOn (Gradle API documentation)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestReport.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestReport:reportOn(java.lang.Object%5B%5D))
- [TestReport#testResults (Gradle API documentation)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestReport.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestReport:testResults)
- [reportOn replacement for gradle 8 (Gradle Forum)](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/reporton-replacement-for-gradle-8/42177)

### test-report-aggregation plugin

There is also alternative option for aggregating tests (Since Gradle 7.4). One can apply [`test-report-aggregation`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/test_report_aggregation_plugin.html)  plugin.
If your projects already apply `java` plugin, this means they will come with `jvm-test-suite`, all you have to do is apply the plugin.

```
plugins {
  id 'test-report-aggregation'
}
```

Then you will be able to invoke test reports through `testSuiteAggregateTestReport` task. Personally didn't use the plugin, but I think it makes sense to use it if you have multiple test suites configured with `jvm-test-suite`.

Example project can be found in https://github.com/gradle-samples/Aggregating-test-results-using-a-standalone-utility-project-Groovy

Answer (score 2):

If using kotlin Gradle DSL

```
val testReport = tasks.register<TestReport>("testReport") {
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/tests/test")
    reportOn(subprojects.map { it.tasks.findByPath("test") })

subprojects {
    tasks.withType<Test> {
        useJUnitPlatform()
        finalizedBy(testReport)
        ignoreFailures = true
        testLogging {
            events("passed", "skipped", "failed")
        }
    }
}
```

And execute `gradle testReport`. Source [How to generate an aggregated test report for all Gradle subprojects](https://dev.to/jakub_zalas/how-to-generate-an-aggregated-test-report-for-all-gradle-subprojects-1me6)

Answer (score 1):

For 'connectedAndroidTest's there is a approach published by google.(https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line.html#RunTestsDevice (**Multi-module reports** section))

1. Add the 'android-reporting' Plugin to your projects build.gradle.

   `apply plugin: 'android-reporting'`
2. Execute the android tests with additional 'mergeAndroidReports' argument. It will merge all test results of the project modules into one report.

   `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest mergeAndroidReports`

Comment: Although the doc says it can also merge the unit tests, running this task depends on espresso tests which is not something I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I've solved this problem using the following `subprojects` config in my root project `build.gradle` file. This way no extra tasks are needed.

Note: this places each module's output in its own `reports/<module_name>` folder, so subproject builds don't overwrite each other's results.

```
subprojects {
 // Combine all build results
  java {
    reporting.baseDir = "${rootProject.buildDir.path}/reports/${project.name}"
  }
}
```

For a default Gradle project, this would result in a folder structure like

```
build/reports/module_a/tests/test/index.html
build/reports/module_b/tests/test/index.html
build/reports/module_c/tests/test/index.html
```

Comment: I dont see how this really answer the question. The question asks about ONE index.html with accumulated results.

Comment: I wanted something exactly like that but this didn't worked for my multi module android project