# How to get Gradle combined test report?

Tags: unit-testing, gradle

I have multiple test suites configured (as shown below) in my gradle build

```
task group1(type: Test) {
  useTestNG() {
    includeGroups 'group1'
  }
  // ... some excluded tests
  ext.useDefaultListeners = true
  ext.workingDirectory = 'build/'
  // ... some system properties required by this test
}

task group2(type: Test, dependsOn: group1) {
  useTestNG() {
    includeGroups 'group2'
  }
  // ... some excluded tests
  ext.useDefaultListeners = true
  ext.workingDirectory = 'build/'
  // ... some system properties required by this test
}

test.dependsOn group2
```

When I run the `gradle clean build --debug`, I could see after every test task (`group1`, `group2` etc), gradle deletes the test report and regenerates it. Hence, after the build is done, whatever report I get does not have any information. All blank!

How can I get a combined report?

Thanks,
NN

Comment: It's a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921384/aggregating-gradle-multiproject-test-results-using-testreport

Hope that helps!

Comment: It is not. The link you gave shows example with `subproject` and I do not have any sub-projects; rather I have many test tasks. Can you show me how to define `reportOn` in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a separate task of type `TestReport`

Check out section '23.12.7. Test reporting' in the [user guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html)