# Aggregating gradle test results from multiple modules

Tags: android, gradle, junit, build.gradle

I have an Android app that has the structure noted below. I would like to know what is the best way to aggregate test reports from all of these modules to a single directory. I have instrumented tests as well as local unit tests in these modules. I did try to use TestReport in build.gradle but that does not seem to work in this case. Thanks for the help.

```
Project
|--ModuleA (android application)
  |--src/test/...
  |--build
    |--reports
      |--tests
        |--index.html (testresults)
        |--..
        |--..
|--ModuleB (android library)
    |--src/test/...
      |--build
        |--reports
          |--tests
            |--index.html (testresults)
            |--..
            |--..
|--ModuleC (android library)
    |--src/test/...
      |--build
        |--reports
          |--tests
            |--index.html (testresults)
            |--..
            |--..
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [aggregating gradle multiproject test results using TestReport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921384/aggregating-gradle-multiproject-test-results-using-testreport)

Comment: No, the answer from that link seems to be ok for combining reports from sub-modules within a module. but not for combining reports from sibling modules.

Comment: Did u find an answer to this question @learner